# How to get error-response packet from apple's Enhanced notification format with javapns

Tags: java, ios, apple-push-notifications

ResponsePacket theErrorResponse = pushedNotification.getResponse();I'm using javapns2.2 and trying to catch error-response packet from from apple's Enhanced notification format. When I send push notification (with invalid token for example) the code

```
Exception theProblem = pushedNotification.getException();
theProblem.printStackTrace();
```

outputs some error to the console, but

```
ResponsePacket theErrorResponse = pushedNotification.getResponse();
if (theErrorResponse != null && theErrorResponse.isErrorResponsePacket()) {
      System.out.println(theErrorResponse.getMessage());
      System.out.println(theErrorResponse.getStatus());
}
```

always returns *null.* How can I obtain status codes with getResponse()?

Here is a part of my code:

```
List<PushedNotification> notifications = Push.payload(payload, keystore, password, production, devices);

        for (PushedNotification pushedNotification : notifications) {
            if(pushedNotification.isSuccessful())
            {
                System.out.println(pushedNotification.getDevice().getToken());                  
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(pushedNotification.getDevice().getToken());

                Exception theProblem = pushedNotification.getException();
                theProblem.printStackTrace();

                ResponsePacket theErrorResponse = pushedNotification.getResponse();
                if (theErrorResponse != null && theErrorResponse.isErrorResponsePacket()) {
                        System.out.println(theErrorResponse.getMessage());
                        System.out.println(theErrorResponse.getStatus());
                }

            }
        }
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

getResponse() returns null because Exception mechanism is preventing the call to APNs to be more efficient. True errors are packed within Exception mechanism.

Everything is super explained at this link:
http://code.google.com/p/javapns/issues/detail?id=79&can=1